# Markdown document on shinyapps: The application failed to start

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny, shiny-server

I created a Rmarkdown document and successfully deployed it to my shinyapps.io server via

```
rsconnect::deployApp()
```

In my account, it says that the App is running.
When I click on the link, I see an error message:

An error has occurred

The application failed to start.

Error in enforcePackage(name, curVersion) : 
 The shiny package was not found in the library.
Calls: local ... eval -> eval -> eval ->  -> enforcePackage
Execution halted

Can anybody give me a hint on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that including library(shiny) in the preamble of the markdown script solves this particular problem.
The document (which includes plotly graphs) still does not work, but this is due to other reasons.